# Symfony single FormType to input data for several Entity attributes?

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

Let's say I have two distinct entities named DanceTeacher and DanceSchool:

```
class DanceTeacher
{
    $firstName;
    $lastName;
    $email;
    $phone;
    $street;
    $city;
}

class DanceSchool
{
    $name;
    $emailContact;
    $phoneContact;
    $street;
    $city;
}
```

I would like to build a FormType regrouping the 4 similar fields:

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class) // serves both teacher email and school emailContact
            ->add('Phone', TextType::class)  // serves both teacher phone and school phoneContact
            ->add('Street', TextType::class) // serves both teacher and school street
            ->add('City', TextType::class)   // serves both teacher and school city
        ;
    }
}
```

Then, my teacher and school forms have some common fields, and I could build them like:

```
class DanceTeacherType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class)
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
            ->add(SOMETHING_HERE, ContactType::class, SOME_OPTIONS)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }
}

class DanceSchoolType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add(SOMETHING_HERE, ContactType::class, SOME_OPTIONS)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }
}
```

Is that possible? I can't find any doc about having a single FormType to write into several entity attributes. I thought I could find options to define some sort of "mapping" between FormType sub-fields and my underlying entities' attributes.

Anyway, put like this, I'm not sure I would win a lot in factorizing in such a way.

Thanks in advance

(oh yes I know, "don't use entities in forms" ;-)

Comment: Why not extends DanceTeacherType from ContactType like `DanceTeacherType extends ContactType` ?

Comment: @qdequippe well the tricky part is how to make this ancestor ContactType map a field named differently across DanceTeacher and DanceSchool entities (e.g. $email vs. $emailContact).

Comment: Is property path is what you need https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path ?

Comment: @qdequippe looks interresting, thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: Well, **property_path** defines a single field path. The path can be a single field, a single cell of an array or a single property of an object, but it is not suitable in my case with multiple fields. In fact, I start to fell that each **$builder->add()** must match a single property of my entity, which would be a Contact object, itself made of several fields email, phone etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to do is documented here :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Form collections seem to be used for nested entities, i.e. entities related to other entities. In my case, the two entities are not related, they just have some similar attributes: each has an e-mail, a phone etc. (the name being different between the entities). I was not looking for a way to have my two entities in a single form.

Comment: Where did you see it was used for nested entities ? You could do a DTO as a model for you FormType with the 4 fields you want. Then build your custom FormType with the data_class set on your your DTO.

Comment: "Where did you see it was used for nested entities ?" in the first sentence of the page: "Symfony Forms can embed a collection of many other forms, which is useful to edit related entities in a single form."
By the way what does DTO stand for?

Comment: Oups... xD
DTO = Data Transfert Object. It's comonly used to map objects into others.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that next week.